# How do you bind to or invoke Foundation functions?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm interested in binding to iOS Foundation functions as seen in the iOS [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html) but there aren't any handles or instances to send a message to invoke them. How would I do this with MonoTouch? I would think that it would involve something within the MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of MonoTouch's NS* objects implement the MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.INativeObject interface which has a property getter called "Handle". This accessor is public on NSObject and all subclasses.

Edit: code to bind `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler()` will be something like this:

```
public delegate void NSUncaughtExceptionHandler (IntPtr exception);

[DllImport ("/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation")]
extern static void NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler (IntPtr handler);
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
static void MyUncaughtExceptionHandler (IntPtr exception)
{
    // Got an exception... 
}

static void Main (string[] args)
{
    NSSetMyUncaughtExceptionHandler (Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(
        new NSUncaughtExceptionHandler(
            MyUncaughtExceptionHandler
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: The problem with your suggestion is that Foundation Functions don't belong to any type of NSObject. They're more like global functions. Can you give me an example of how I would call a function like `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler`?